# SASS/SCSS - Simple `display: none` property gets scrambled at compile time

Tags: css, sass

I have this SASS (SCSS) definition :

```
@media #{$mq_phone} {
    .no-phone: {
        display: none;
    } 
}
```

When compiling, it becomes :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .no-phone-display: none; 
}
```

I am puzzled

What I expected :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .no-phone: { display: none; }
}
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Remove the ":" character between the class name and the "{" and it should work.

`.no-phone: {...}` ----> `.no-phone {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the colon `:` at the end of `.no-phone:` selector, as follows:

```css
@media #{$mq_phone} {
    .no-phone {
        display: none;
    } 
}
```

**[Demo](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9504658)**

Comment: I realized that at the moment you answered :) Thanks anyway, the more obvious bugs are the harder to spot !